# Convert String into a two dimensional array

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, converters

I try to convert this string

> s=[[4, 2, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1, 4]]
>   into a two dimensional array like this
>   {4, 2, 2, 4},
>   {3, 4, 5, 6},
>   {6, 7, 8,9},
>   {3, 2, 1, 4}

by use this code

```
 int e=s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("],","]").length();
        String[] rows1 = s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("],","]").substring(0, e-2).split("]");

        String[][] matrix1 = new String[4][4]; 
        int r1 = 0;
        for (String row1 : rows1) {
            matrix[r1++] = row1.split(",");
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix1));
```

But is have problem like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at test.main(test.java:94)

Can you help me find a solution?

Comment: Which line is line 94?

Comment: This line           matrix[r1++] = row1.split(",");

Comment: Did you look up an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to make an effort to understand what it is and why it happens? Did you use your debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Ok i will try to search that

Comment: I think your trying to alter the wrong variable here `matrix[r1++] = row1.split(",");`. Shouldn't it be `matrix1`? Try using variable names which do a little bit in explaining what the variables role is.

Comment: As @ug_ pointed out, you're accessing a variable that doesn't exits: `matrix`.  I just tested your code and it worked for me with `matrix` changed to `matrix1`.

Answer (score 9):

I think this code will help you. Read the all comments carefully.

```
     String s="[[4, 2, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1, 4]]";
     s=s.replace("[","");//replacing all [ to ""
     s=s.substring(0,s.length()-2);//ignoring last two ]]
     String s1[]=s.split("],");//separating all by "],"

     String my_matrics[][] = new String[s1.length][s1.length];//declaring two dimensional matrix for input

     for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++){
         s1[i]=s1[i].trim();//ignoring all extra space if the string s1[i] has
         String single_int[]=s1[i].split(", ");//separating integers by ", "

         for(int j=0;j<single_int.length;j++){
             my_matrics[i][j]=single_int[j];//adding single values
         }
     }

     //printing result
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             System.out.print(my_matrics[i][j]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }
```

**[[4, 2, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1, 4]]**

Logic: 
1) replacing all [ to "" now I have-> **4, 2, 2, 4], 3, 4, 5, 6], 6, 7, 8, 9], 3, 2, 1, 4]]**

2) Separating all by "]," now I have->

**A) 4, 2, 2, 4**

**B) 3, 4, 5, 6**

**c) 6, 7, 8, 9**

**d) 3, 2, 1, 4**

3) Separating A B C D by ", " now I have->

**A) a) 4 b) 2 c) 2 d) 4**

**B) a) 3 b) 4 c) 5 d) 6**

**c) a) 6 b) 7 c) 8 d) 9**

**d) a) 3 b) 2 c) 1 d) 4**

Comment: ok. But this line : s1[i]=s1[i].trim(); just make result more beautifull, right?

Answer (score 4):

Solution using Java streams:

```
String[][] arr = Arrays.stream(str.substring(2, str.length() - 2).split("\\],\\["))
.map(e -> Arrays.stream(e.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
.toArray(String[]::new)).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
String s="[[4, 2, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1, 4]]";

// Split on this delimiter
String[] rows = s.split("], \\[");
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // Remove any beginning and ending braces and any white spaces
    rows[i] = rows[i].replace("[[", "").replace("]]", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
}

// Get the number of columns in a row
int numberOfColumns = rows[0].split(",").length;

// Setup your matrix
String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][numberOfColumns];

// Populate your matrix
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = rows[i].split(",");
}
// Display your matrix
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This just doesn't add the comma's at the end of the line:

```
    String s = "[[4, 2, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1, 4]]";
    for (String l: s.split("\\]\\s*,\\s*\\[")) {
        l = l.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
        System.out.println("{" + l + "}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input string will always be in that format, with 4 integers between each bracket, I think the best way to do it would simply be to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object and it's nextInt() method which will ignore the brackets and comma's and just find the numbers. Then put them into a 2d array like how you would with a loop.

It kinda gets rid of all the fun you were having with removing the brackets though, so it's not really better in terms of making an exercise out of this.